# Virtuemart Add to Cart Sends to User Homepage Due to URL When Using an Intro Page

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am using Joomla 1.5x and have installed Virtuemart.  I've got an intro page to the main site which is a child of "Home" in the main menu.  In order to make the intro page the first thing you see, you have to make it the default in the main menu...  You can see my setup at dirtygertie.samwinans.com.

If you click Purchase Soaps! and then the Dirty Gertie Goat Milk Soaps Category in the content then you get to a list of products (right now there is just one).  Clicking "Add to Cart" takes me back to the Intro page again and I think it's because that is the default in the main menu.  The default template, however, is my regular template... not my intro-page template.

Can anyone help me make it so adding to cart goes to the actual cart (I believe it's the flypage...)

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: Reply #53 fixes the URL issue.  Not a whole lot of testing completed, but appears to be fixed.  Hope this helps someone.